# Eliminate duplicates from a array of characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have to eliminate duplicates from a array of characters using pointers and a function. 
I can t get it to work correctly:

```
void del_copy(char *p){
int n = strlen(p);          
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){           // Element that we compare
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n;j++){     //We compare p + i element with the rest of the elements
        if (*(p + i) == *(p + j)){        //If we find two similar, we eliminate that element by shifting
            for (int k = i; k < n; k++)
                *(p + k) = *(p + k + 1);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::unique` comes to mind. isn't it possible to just add a little "using pointers and a function"?

Comment: You need to define the problem better. Give example input and output. Should `aaabbbaaa` become `aba`? Should it become `ab`?

Comment: Create a table of `char tbl[1 << CHAR_BIT] = {0}`. Walk the string, each character you encounter only keep it if `tbl[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)]++ == 0`. That's it.

Comment: And btw, *pick a language*. It can *significantly* effect the answers received.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining two strings into one string which eliminates the same letters in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334684/combining-two-strings-into-one-string-which-eliminates-the-same-letters-in-c)

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun It should become ab, with no duplicates.

Comment: Removed C++ tag from title, C tag from tag list. But I agree with WhozCraig: C and C++ are two different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do a shift the length changes. But your n doesn't take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple algorithm:

let *s* be the empty set (characters encountered so far)
    let *result* be an empty string
    for each character *c* in the input string (
        if *c* is not in *s* (
            include *c* in *s* and
            append *c* to the end of *result*
            )
        )
    *result* is the result

For the `char` type on an ordinary machine with 8-bit byte, you can just use a `std::bitset` as set `s`.

Another simple algorithm is to sort the string first, if there is no requirement on preserving order. Then you can just scan it and look for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take at the problem. It basically uses a lookup table to check if the character has been seen before but is templated. You could use any kind of `value_type`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename Container>
Container unique_all(Container const& c) {
  Container out;
  ::std::unordered_map<typename Container::value_type,::std::size_t> lookup;
  ::std::copy_if(c.begin(), c.end(),
      ::std::back_inserter(out),
      [&](typename Container::value_type ch) {return !lookup[ch]++;}); 
  return out;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
unique_all(::std::string("hello dear world"))
```

Answer (score 0):

sample to fix

```
void del_copy(char *p){
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; c=*(p+i); i++){
        char *p2, *p3;
        for(p2 = p+i+1, p3 = p2; *p3; ++p3){
            if(*p3 != c)
                *p2++ = *p3;
        }
        *p2 = '\0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix my own code also. Thank you everyone for support. 
I had to change the if loop for a while loop and to decrement de lenght @ScottMcP-MVP.

```
void del_copy(char *p){
int n = strlen(p);          
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){           // Element that we compare
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n;j++){     //We compare p + i element with the rest of the elements
        while(*(p + i) == *(p + j)){        //If we find two similar, we eliminate that element by shifting
            for (int k = j; k < n; k++)
                *(p + k) = *(p + k + 1);
            n--;                             //decrement n because the lenght if smaller now
        }               
    }
}
}
```